# React - server side component rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to renderToString a very simple React component on the server:

```
/** @jsx dom */
var React = require("react");

var Title = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(<h1>Hello World</h1>) 
  }
});

module.exports = React.createFactory(Title);
```

When I call ReactDOMServer.renderToString (Component) I'm getting `Error: Invariant Violation: renderToString(): You must pass a valid ReactElement.`

If I do React.createElement (Title) instead, I get

```
return(dom.h1(null, "Hello World")) 
           ^
ReferenceError: dom is not defined
```

Routes file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    React = require("react")
    ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");  
    JSX = require('node-jsx').install({
      extension: '.jsx'
    }),
    AssessmentComponent = require("../react/components/title.react.jsx");
```

I have no idea why this isn't working!

Comment: Why aren't you just returning `Title`? Also I recommend you use `babel/register` instead of `node-jsx` which was deprecated 6months ago and could also be causing problems

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I stripped out node-jsx to replace with Babel transpiling, but I'm still getting the same Invariant Vioation error. When you say just return title what do you mean exactly? This is just a trial to get it working, but the component will have much more complexity.

Comment: PS I forgot you are not using jsx in that server file (since you can't use it in the file which calls `babel/register`. So yeah you could need to wrap it in `React.createElement` (or createFactory I guess).. so yeah not sure what's wrong

Comment: Have you tried removing `React.createFactory` from the `module.export`? I feel like that could break things easily.

Comment: Youre right Calebmer, it didn't like my export. I had implemented this method before without difficulty. But the deprecation of React.DOM and other changes means that this implementation was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was making a few mistakes. Solutions below:

a) Using babel/register when requiring the component meant that transpiling can be done on the fly without any faff ;)

b) dom was being inserted by Babel's @jsx dom syntax. No need for that now that babel/register is being used.

c) Exporting the component with createFactory is not advised because other users of the component may want to call createElement on it.

d) I called createFactory on the routes file, but it appears to return a function which needed to be called. - `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(Component())`

Comment: Why `babel/register`? There is no any `babel/register` in the docs. There is only `require("babel-core/register");`. So why do you suggest it?

Comment: babel-core/register is the new methodology, as of babel v6 . You now have to use include the plugin with babelrc file: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/